# Adding Columns to a JTable with an abstract table model

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, jtable

I'm trying to create a attendance list with Java. I'm using a `JTable` with an abstract table model. The problem is that I want to add new columns to the table, but if I create a new column with `addColumn` the first and new column are identical, I tried to change the data in the new column with this method:

```
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
    data[row][col] = value;
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
}
```

But this method changes the content of the first and the new column. I'm also not able to change the content to a new Boolean, if I try to do that the whole table is broken and the stacktrace says that String cannot be cast to Boolean. The tablemodel uses the following two arrays:

```
private String[] columnNames = {"Name",
                    "10.01.19","17.01.19"};
private Object[][] data ={
{"Kathy", new Boolean(true), new Boolean(true)},
{"John", new Boolean(true), new Boolean(true)},
{"Sue", new Boolean(true), new Boolean(true)},
{"Jane", new Boolean(true), new Boolean(true)},
{"Joe", new Boolean(true), new Boolean(true)}
```

I want to know how I can add a new column to the table without the same content as the table model has. I was only able to change the header of the new column without changing the header of the first one.

```
TableColumn column = new TableColumn();
column.setHeaderValue(new String("24.01.2019"));
table.addColumn(column);
table.setValueAt(new Boolean(true),0,3);
```

Comment: And `getValueAt` works how?

Comment: `public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];
    }`